# Is it possible to use ControllerBase for API in Azure Functions?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm in the processing of migrating some ASP.NET Core Web APIs to Azure Functions (C# .NET 5).

It's mostly painless as the code logic is identical and Azure Functions supports the same `IActionResult` outputs as well as DI.

But one thing I missed is the `ControllerBase` class used in ASP.NET Core web API projects, which is a much lighter weight version of the full MVC `Controller`, with added convenience for returning results, such as `return NotFound()`.

In Azure Functions it seems to use the full MVC class, and we have to do things like `return new NotFoundResult()`.

Also it's my understanding that `ControllerBase` is much faster being lightweight without all the model/view stuff in the pipeline.

So is it possible to use it in Azure Functions?

Comment: You can use it as there is nothing stopping you from inheriting from `ControllerBase` but a lot of the properties of the base class wont be populated since that is usually done by the framework in Web API / MVC which is not present in Azure Functions.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, arguably using Functions is itself a problem that tweaking code won't solve. Functions is built for dynamic scale, not to perform as well as a dedicated ASP.NET Core app.